Copy from VS code to Powerpoint: how do I get single line spacing?
I copy/paste code from VS Code to PowerPoint. I want to keep the VS Code formatting.
However, the line spacing looks very different.
Can I define something in settings.json so that when I paste in PowerPoint, the line spacing becomes "single".
I have the following code in VS code:
VS code
In PowerPoint, my "line spacing" is defined as "single":
Paragraph settings 1
Then I paste the code from VS code to PowerPoint and I get:
PowerPoint 1
As you can see, in PowerPoint the lines are compressed. It is not single line spacing anymore. The paragraph settings have changed to:
Paragraph settings 2
I tried the following in settings.json from VS code:
"editor.lineHeight": 1.5
The line spacing will become 15.75, which looks a little better. However, If I would change the font to a smaller font, it looks bad again.
Problem is of course that the formatting is copied from VS Code (and I want that, I do want to get the syntax highlighting from VS Code).
Does anyone has an advice?
